# How can I add an alert popup with yes/no responses using Greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey

I am trying to create a script that will auto-popup with a window prompting agents to check to see if the ticket needs to be marked as a complaint, I can already create the function to mark it as a complaint but can't figure out how to get the yes/no option to appear.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please share some code, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: The simplest method is [confirm()](http://devdocs.io/dom/window/confirm).